# Custom status - disnake

Tags: python

С недавнего времени ботам позволили дела свои кастомные статусы в discord, как это можно реализовать через disnake/discord.py.

формат поставки статуса такой:

```
activity = disnake.Activity(
    name="фильм",
    type=disnake.ActivityType.watching
)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=disnake.Intents.all(), help_command=None, activity=activity)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
await bot.change_presence(activity=disnake.Streaming(name="Название статус", url='ссылка на твич стрим (допустим)'))
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].